# Is there a quick way to retrieve documentation of OpenGL ES functions and symbols in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, documentation, opengl-es-2.0

While learning OpenGL ES 2.0 I find it inconvenient to look up OpenGL ES related symbols like `glBindFramebuffer` online. Maybe there is a better way? Is there a better documentation browser for OpenGL ES?

Comment: Apparently this existed way back in Xcode 2.3 :   http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2008/Jan/msg00135.html  but was removed because of some problem indexing stuff automatically.  At this point opengl is such a huge supported API on both OS X and iOS that you would hope they are working on re-adding it...  anyone know a radar we can dupe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess there are the OpenGL ES 2.0 Reference Pages (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/), but that *is* online.

You could always print the [Quick Reference Card](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/2.0/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf), that is helpful, but only if you know a little bit about the functions in question.

And finally, if working in C++, you could give a try to [GLES Emulator](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj_glesemu.htm). This was written by a colleague of mine, it contains OpenGL ES 2.0 headers with documentation comments extracted from online documentation. You can:
 - either use it directly in Visual Studio or Eclipse
 - generate Doxygen out of it, to get offline version of the OpenGL documentation
 - use some bash magic to transfer the comments from "C" header file to NDK class file

Hope this helps ...
(and sorry abouth the link, i lack reputation to post >2 links)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find offline documentation so I packaged [Dash Docsets](https://github.com/chinmaygarde/OpenGLESDashDocset) for OpenGL ES 2.0 and 1.1. If you dont use Dash, you can still refer to the HTML documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ wget -r -l 2 http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way. Not exactly for XCode, but I think it is still useful.

It is possible to clone repository with source code of all OpenGL docs. Use your favorite SVN or CVS client:

```
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/manglsl glsl
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man2 opengl_2
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man3 opengl_3
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man4 opengl_4
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogles/trunk/sdk/docs opengl_es_2_3
svn co --username anonymous --password anonymous https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/egl/sdk/docs opengl_es_1
```

After that, you will need to find appropriate an 'index.php' file and open it in browser.
This way you will get man pages with an index on the left side, just like in offline docs.

You can grab more if you wish: there are at least "Super Bible" book sources at "ecosystem" repository. Just navigate some levels up.

See wiki page for details: 
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started/XML_Toolchain_and_Man_Pages